# Strange information when getting app version information

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, winui-3

i have a winui 3 app and i am using this code for getting app version info:

```
assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()?.InformationalVersion
```

Previously, I had Windows 11 - 22H2 and Visual Studio 2022 v17.7 + net7.0
And the output of the above code was as follows:

```
4.0.0
```

Today I changed Windows (Clean Install) to 23H2 and Visual Studio 2022 v17.8 /Visual Studio 2022 v18.0-Preview1 + net8.0
but when i run my app (from visual studio) The output of the above code is almost as follows:

```
4.0.0 + ea32asd354ad5a4d5a4sda5a54da54da4das54da4d
```

i changed .net version to net7.0 or i moved to previous versions (from git) and output is strange.
but when i run my app from ms store output is correct, or when i create a new project output is correct but i dont know why my project is curropted

Comment: Looks like that somehow the `--versionSuffix` argument of `dotnet build` is used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#:~:text=no%20longer%20occur.-,%2D%2Dversion%2Dsuffix%20%3CVERSION_SUFFIX%3E,-Sets%20the%20value

Comment: @Serg so... how to fix?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the exact fix. You should find the place where this option is added in the your specific environment and remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is a breaking change.
As discussed in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-adds-string-to-assembly-Informatio/10515014) a new behavior has been included in .NET SDK: [Source Link included in the .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/source-link).

To get the previous behavior and avoid that the commit id be shown in the AssemblyInformationalVersion include the following setting in your .csproj file:

```
<IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
```

If there are multiple projects in the solution I would recommend to add the setting in the "[Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets)" file instead of adding the setting in each project file. "Directory.Build.props" file must be in the root folder that contains your source and must be similar to this:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
      <IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>false</IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: excelent, fixed

Comment: i have a question, i have a vsix template app, so i added this option for net8.0, do i need to add this for net7.0 and 6.0? if i understand correctly, this behavior added into new vs version! can you clarify?

Comment: You must add the setting per project (.csproj) file, not per Target Framework. I you have more than one project you can use the "Directory.Build.props" approach. I edited my answer to include it.
If this doesn't answer your question please include an example.

Comment: i know it. i mean, this feature added and enabled by default with new Visual studio, and not net8.0, yes? because i tested with net8.0 and net7.0 and i should add property for both, so this is not matter we have net8.0 or net7.0, we should add IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion if we are using new vs

Comment: As described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/8.0/source-link#new-behavior the new behavior has been added to .Net 8 (not Visual Studio 17.8) and should only affect to .Net 8 but It affects to all targets (net8.0,net7.0,net48...).
I have asked Visual Studio Team to reconsider it as a bug:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Build-adds-string-to-assembly-Informatio/10515014#T-N10516964-N10524297
In conclusion, I don't know the reason but if you are using Visual Studio 17.8+ you must add IncludeSourceRevisionInInformationalVersion for all targetings